# View reappears in UITableViewCell after scrolling off and on

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a UITableView with 2 sections. In the first section I do not want the UIView I have created to appear on the left. It works fine when it initially loads but when it goes off screen and back on again it reappears.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! ATableCell;
    cell.delegate = self;

    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        // let height = cell.bounds.size.height;
        let height = 100;

        let turnsView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: height));
        turnsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple;

        cell.addSubview(turnsView);
    }
    else
    {
        let height = 100;

        let turnsView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: height));
        turnsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;

        cell.addSubview(turnsView);
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
    cell.textLabel?.text = "texting";
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "testing";
}
```

I don't want the purple view appearing in the first section at any point.

Comment: assign a tag to your views and before creating them use if-let statement to remove them if they already exist in the cell. I had a similar problem where my uilabels kept reappearing on my cells when scrolling would start.

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You should use  Every "if" condition with its "else" clause as when you scroll on off it reuses the cell that cause it to reappear. So if you  not write else condition and if condition become false it will use old cell data.

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid adding subviews to cell in cellForRow. You need to understand that the cells are reused and when you add the subView in cellForRow, the subView is not removed each time. So if the cell appears for 10 times due to scrolling on and off, 10 subViews would be added to the reused cell.

In your case same thing is happening. I would suggest you to add the view in XIB/Prototype cell. Give it a reference and change its backgroundColor property in cellForRow.

Or if you are not using XIB or prototype cell, add subview in init method in your cell class.

```
var turnsView = UIView()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    turnsView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 100)) 
    self.contentView.addSubview(turnsView)

}
```

Comment: So create the view in awakeFromNib in cell subclass. Set it as a tag. Then in cellForRow alter the background color? Correct? I hope so.

Comment: Create a public variable turnsView in your cell. Create and add it in awakeFromNib. Then in cellForRow set its property like turnsView.backgroundColor = .purple

Comment: If you are using nib/Storyboard prototype cell, I would suggest to add the view there and give reference. If not, add it in init method like mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! ATableCell;
    cell.delegate = self;

    //Remove subviews before adding again
    if let purpleV = cell.viewWithTag(1) {
        purpleV.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    if let purpleV = cell.viewWithTag(2) {
        purpleV.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        // let height = cell.bounds.size.height;
        let height = 100;

        let turnsView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: height));
        turnsView.tag = 1
        turnsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple;

        cell.addSubview(turnsView);
    }
    else
    {
        let height = 100;

        let turnsView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: height));
        turnsView.tag = 2
        turnsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;

        cell.addSubview(turnsView);
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
    cell.textLabel?.text = "texting";
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "testing";
}
```

Read the documentation for dequeuereusablecell method to clarify.

Comment: This will work but  is not a good solution. The addition and removal of subViews in cellForRow will give jerks while scrolling(scrolling will not be smooth). Always avoid that.

Comment: I agree, not a good solution but i dont experience any jerking, the scrolling is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

This will be good to do as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    // Config the cell...
    if let turnsCell as? ATableCell {
        turnsCell.turnsColor = (indexPath.section == 1 ? UIColor.purple : UIColor.clear)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "texting"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "testing"

    return cell
}

class ATableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var turnsView = UIView()

    var turnsColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return self.turnsView.backgroundColor
        }
        set {
            self.turnsView.backgroundColor = newValue
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // let height = self.bounds.size.height;
        let height = 100;

        turnsView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: height)
        self.contentView.addSubview(turnsView)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```